# Plotting gam model output - not component smooth functions

Tags: r, data-visualization, generalized-additive-model

I aim to model the temperature variations in two locations in America, example below:

```
set.seed(10)
RandData <- runif(8760*2)
America <- rep(c('NewYork','Miami'),each=8760)

Date = seq(from=as.POSIXct("1991-01-01 00:00"), 
           to=as.POSIXct("1991-12-31 23:00"), length=8760)

DatNew <- data.frame(Loc = America,
                    Doy = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%j")),
                    Tod = as.numeric(format(Date,format = "%H")),
                    Temp = RandData)
require(mgcv)
mod1 <- gam(Temp ~ Loc + s(Doy) + s(Doy,by = Loc) +
  s(Tod) + s(Tod,by = Loc),data = DatNew)

plot(mod1,pages = 1, scale = 0)
```

Instead of having an output showing the component smooth functions that make up the gam I would like to plot the model output on the original x and y axis i.e. show the temperatures on the y axis. When modelling 1 location I would use something along the lines of:

```
pred <- data.frame(Doy = DatNew$Doy)
pred <- transform(pred, yhat = predict(mod1, newdata = pred))
```

However, I do not know how to achieve this if I have several locations i.e. the model depends on the location not solely on the day of year/time of day.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Kate when I run your code, I get the following error from the last line, which is the key to the solution:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Loc' not found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In predict.gam(mod1, newdata = pred) :
>     not all required variables have been supplied in  newdata!

If you want to predict from a model, any model not just `gam()`, you must provide all the variables in the dataframe to predict from (the argument newdata).

```
pred <- data.frame(Doy = 1:365,  Tod=median(DatNew$Tod),
    Loc=factor('NewYork',levels=levels(DatNew$Loc)))
predict(mod1, newdata = pred)
```

And this works giving a predicted value of temperature for each day of the year in New York, assuming that they are measured at the median time of day. I tweaked your Doy values to be simply from 1 to 365, as presumably you only want one prediction for each day of the year. The value is almost completely flat because you simulated the data with no effect of Doy on temp, and it is almost exactly the expected value for a uniform(0,1) distribution, which is how you generated your random temperatures.

Comment: Thanks for this. However, from this how can I obtain the same plots as plot(mod1,pages = 1, scale = 0) but with the new predicted values, i.e. altering the axis of the plot produced by gam?

Comment: @Kate I'm not sure what you mean by altering the axis - if you do plot(mod1) it shows you the component smooths without the intercepts, so the y-axis scale will be centered around 0. When you use predict(mod1, ...) you are getting all of the model, including the intercepts, combined in a single value.

Answer (score 4):

You might want

```
predvals <- predict(mod1, newdata = pred, type = "terms")
```

That returns a column for each smoother in the model such that each `by` gets its own column.

You can then plot each column individually as the y axis variable by adding on the the constant term:

```
lines(predvals[, i] + attr(predvals, "constant"), ....)
```

where `i` is the ith columns of `predvals`. You can also get standard errors for each smooth by adding `se.fit` to the `predict()` call. Then you will need to plot from the `$fit` component.

The constant term contains the overall mean of the entire data set normally, but as you have `Loc` it will be the mean of `Temp` for the reference location (i.e. that given by `levels(Loc)[1]`). Hence you will also need to adjust `predvals[, i]` not only by the constant term but also by the relevant coefficient (or effect) for `Loc`. There will be a column in `predvals` for each level of `LOC` (minus the reference level which is the constant term).